# Subqueries vs Multi Table Join

Tags: sql, inner-join, subquery

I've 3 tables A, B, C. I want to list the intersection count.

Way 1:-

```
select count(id) from A a join B b on a.id = b.id join C c on  B.id = C.id;
```

**Result Count - X**

Way 2:-

```
SELECT count(id) FROM A WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM B WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM C));
```

**Result Count - Y**

The result count in each of the query is different. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: The JOIN version may return duplicated id's, to be counted several times.

Answer (score 2):

A `JOIN` can multiply the number of rows as well as filtering out rows.

In this case, the second count should be the correct one because nothing is double counted -- assuming `id` is unique in `a`.  If not, it needs `count(distinct a.id)`.

The equivalent using `JOIN` would use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
select count(distinct a.id)
from A a join
     B b
     on a.id = b.id join
     C c
     on B.id = C.id;
```

I mention this for completeness *but do not recommend this approach*.  Multiplying the number of rows just to remove them using `distinct` is inefficient.

In many databases, the most efficient method might be:

```
select count(*)
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id) and
      exists (select 1 from c where c.id = a.id);
```

Note:  This assumes there are indexes on the `id` columns and that `id` is unique in `a`.

Comment: Tried all 3 solutions on 10M records:- `JOINs including distinct`  take 45secs, `exists` take 46 secs, and `nested Select` takes 52 secs.

Comment: Measuring time for query wont help you always to find optimum solution. Please check for query plan for each of the approach, Adding joins and than distinct will add overhead for final result.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast . . . Does the `exists` have the recommended indexes?  Does it require `select distinct`?